# html bootstrap table not responsive with unordered list inside

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I run this code in small screen 320x568 the table contents overflow the whole div that contains it. Is there any way to work around this. I am expect him to compress or shrink a bit just to fit in the container. Thanks

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row ">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:20px">
          <p><strong>PART A - Reading Material </strong></p>
          <ul style="list-style-type:roman">
            <li><span class="blueprint">Self-help books</span></li>
            <li><span class="blueprint">Annotation sources</span></li>
            <li>Academic references
              <ul>
                <li><span class="blueprint">printed</span></li>
                <li><span class="blueprint">online</span></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class="blueprint">Editions of Batman</span></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td style="padding:20px">
          <p><strong>Part B – Audio & Visual Material</strong></p>
          <ul start="5" style="list-style-type:roman; ">
            <li><span class="blueprint">Lectures on DVD</span></li>
            <li><span class="blueprint">YouTube original content</span></li>
            <li><span class="blueprint">Films & TV productions</span></li>
            <li><span class="blueprint">Audio recordings</span></li>
          </ul>
          <br>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td style="padding:20px">
          <p><strong>PART C – Material by Level</strong></p>
          <ul start="9" style="list-style-type:roman; ">
            <li><span class="blueprint">Introduction</span></li>
            <li><span class="blueprint">Variety of Materials</span></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: where the css based on this div, table ??

Comment: Tables shouldn't really be used for content, because it is bad for SEO. They should only be used for data sets. Also tables aren't very responsive. I would suggest using grids and making them stack on mobile.

Comment: The only other solution would be to reduce the padding on the `td`s and greatly reduce the font size for small screen, but this would make the content hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is a but hard considering there is no css to work off of as of now. Try using percentages for your divs. Then when they shrink to a size that's too small use @media queries to define the width you'd like to stop floating- add a float:none or auto. Also for images like your logo or something make sure to include img {max-width:100%;}- this will get them to scale nicely.

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    width:50%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  div {
    width:40%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  div {
    width:20%;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** In mobile, you would need to stack the tables, which you cant do using a table. Thanks @WizardCoder

Comment: I think the main issue is that they are using tables to layout their content.

Comment: That is true @WizardCoder, but if im not mistaken, you can do the media resizing to the <td> elements

Comment: You are right, but I think in this instance they should be stacking the columns on mobile, which you can't do with tables,